# How to check whether any data is provided in array or not in C?

Tags: c

I am making a program that sorts integers in ascending and descending order through bubble sort algorithm in C. So, I am providing a random data of 20 integers(fixed)first and then deciding in which manner to sort it, which is basically done through simple menu system which is like:

```
A. provide random data
B. Sort high to low
C. Sort low to high
```

**I want to print a message "Data not provided" if the user tries to sort without getting the random data first.*

Code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void random_number_list(int array[]);
void low_to_high(int array[]);
void high_to_low(int array[]);
void display(int array[]);

int main(void)
{
    int original_array[21];
    char selection;

    
    do 
    {
        puts("----> Please make your selection from the following:\n\n"
       " A.Define Random Number List\n"
       " B.Sort Number List(High to Low)\n"
       " C.Sort Number List(Low to High)\n"
       " D.Exit ");

        printf_s(" \nYour selection: ");
        scanf_s("\n%c", &selection);
        
        if (selection == 'A' || selection == 'a')
        {
            
             random_number_list(original_array);
        }
        else if (selection == 'B' || selection == 'b')
        {
                high_to_low(original_array);
        }
        else if (selection == 'C' || selection == 'c')
        {
                low_to_high(original_array);
        }
        else if (selection == 'D' || selection == 'd')
        {
            puts("\nThank you for using the application.\n");
        
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("\nSorry, input not understood. Please try again.\n");
        }
    } 
    while (selection != 'D');
}

void random_number_list(int array[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n\nThe Random Data: ");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 1 + rand() % 100;
        printf_s("%d,", array[i]);
        
    }
    puts("\n\n");

}

void low_to_high(int array[])
{
    int i, j, temp;

        for (i = 0;i < 20 - 1;i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1;j < 20;j++)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[j])
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;

                    display(array);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        printf_s("\nSorted Data : ");
        
        display(array);
        puts("\n");
}

void high_to_low(int array[])
{
    int i, j, temp;
    
        for (i = 0; i < 20 - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < 20; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[j])
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;

                    display(array);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        printf_s("\nSorted Data : ");

        display(array);
        puts("\n");
}

void display(int array[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by random data here ? And please provide minimal code what you have tried till now.

Comment: Show your existing (even incomplete or wrong) code. Otherwise we can't help other than tell you: you need to write the code that does what you want.

Comment: @SMVaidhyanathan   i am providing random data by srand(time(NULL))

Comment: OT: your usage of `srand` is wrong: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

Comment: @Jabberwocky i know, the compiler is already giving a warning but my concern is that data being provided or not and if not then notify that data is not provided

Comment: @DeepPatel yes, that's why I wrote __OT__ meaning "off topic". An off topic comment is a kind of bonus comment which points out a different problem than the one being asked about.

Answer (score 3):

What about using a boolean flag indicating whether option A was called? Initialize that flag with `false` and set it `true` in option A. Then in options B and C, test if the flag is `true`. If `false`, complain.

Showing us the code you have so far would be helpful.

Comment: @DeepPatel Wonderful! The next step on Stackoverflow then is to accept the answer that was most helpful. (And maybe upvote all answers that helped you, which can be more than one).

Comment: I did but stackoverflow says it will not display my upvotes as I dont have enough reputation . sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would include `stdbool.h` and create a boolean variable in the main function called something like `is_generated` set to false by default and set it to true when the option A is entered. Then you can check it instead of checking if `original_array` is equal to zero.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `sizeof` operator and divide the result by the size of an element.

`size_t n = sizeof your_array`

Comment: This response does not make much sense without seeing OP's code.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.